# windows registry - default file extension program - working for new ext not working for existing

Tags: windows, windows-installer, registry

I am experiencing problem with windows registry.
I have an MSI installation file and I want to set that all mp3 files will be opened by my new program by default.

I have done the following:

`Created key with ext .mp3 in HKCR and set default value to myapp.mp3
Created key myapp.mp3 in HKCR with subkeys shell > open > command.
Created default value in key command "PATH-TO-MY-APP\myapp.exe" "%1"`

So when I install my app - mp3 file default program does not change....

However If i do this with custom extension (like I made up my own).
I added one more key in HKCR with name .test and default value "myapp.mp3" and I can see that this is working with my new extension.
When I press on test.test file it opens with myapp. But not working for existing extension..

Please help this is a headache!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx
<-- recent versions of windows require programs to have a registration first, otherwise they'll be ignored when considering how to open a document.

Comment: Most tools that build MSI setups have a way to just do this without fiddling in the registry directly. WiX has ProgID, Visual Studio setups do it. That would be the preferable way.